# Is there a way to make /tmp mounted as tmpfs to use only swap?

Tags: linux, memory, swap, tmpfs

I have a swap of 64 GB SSD. So is there a way to make /tmp mounted as tmpfs to use swap alone and not use RAM?

Comment: Sounds like too much work. Besides, tmpfs will automatically be swapped out if necessary, so you don't need to do anything. If this isn't sufficient, why not just put `/tmp` on the SSD?

Comment: Uhm... tmpfs entirely on swap is generally called "a disk partition".

Comment: @womble Actually not. That will also get cached in memory.

Comment: That is true.  Not using RAM is actually rather tricky on a computer system...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not quite clear what you're asking.  [tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt) is an in-memory filesystem but you apparently don't want the contents of `/tmp` to actually reside in memory, is that right?

Then you simply don't use tmpfs and instead use an ordinary on-disk `/tmp` **directory** or dedicated partition with a normal file-system.

Comment: It might be added that even a mounted disk filesystem will take up some memory by using the block cache.